# What is it called when you repeat a part of a word?

Tags: sentence, questions

For example, in the movie My Cousin Vinny, a character named Rothenstein, who pronounces the last part of his name "Steen", upon hearing his name pronounced Rothen"Stine", objects saying something like:

Stine!  Did you hear that?  She said Stine.

Answer (score 0):

Linguists use terms like "phoneme" and "morpheme," derived from the Greek words for "sound" and "shape," respectively. A phoneme is the smallest unit of sound in a language, and a morpheme is the smallest unit of meaning in a language.

So in Rothenstein, each letter would be a phoneme except T and H, which together form a single phoneme that represents the -th sound.

Roth, meanwhile, is presumably a morpheme derived from another language. I believe that it's from the German for "red." (While the R sound by itself carries no meaning.) The "stein" part is also a morpheme because it means something, probably stone. (Guggenheimer and Guggenheimer, *Jewish Family Names and Their Origins: An Etymological Dictionary*).

Morpheme vs. phoneme: http://www.grammarbank.com/phoneme-and-morpheme.html

Comment: Side note - Stein in German-Jewish names refers to jewels, precious stones. With age-old laws disallowing owning land or entering trades, Jews became jewelers, hence Rubinstein (ruby) and perhaps Rothenstein, Silverstein, Goldstein, Shapiro (sapphire).

Comment: Is there ANY way that people could try to answer the question rather than trying show just how smart they are in virtue of knowing words like phoneme and morpheme and a few factoids about them--or about the history of Yiddish?  Just wondering here.

Comment: Relax, guy, I misunderstood the question. I thought the question asked whether there was a term for certain parts of words, like -stein. Believe it or not, some people genuinely enjoy sharing knowledge for its own sake. Now for a question of my own: Are you here to help answer the question or just criticize?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. I see no term for what it's called when you repeat part of a word.

Comment: It's a syllable (at least) that's being reiterated here.

Answer (score 0):

It is called reduplication.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication

I am fairly certain that this is what you mean but I apologize if it is not

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/418514)

Comment: 'Reduplication' is used in morphological studies, not (usually) in part-quotes to highlight pronunciation .